# Stuck in Aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have joined two tables, ACTIVITY(Which has PK ACTIVITYID and details related to activity), NODE(which stores NODEs pertaining to ACTIVITY) and have the following sample data

```
Year  WeekNUM   ACTIVITYID   NODEID  ACTIVITY_HOURS_SPENT
2014    36           A1         N1             1
2014    36           A1         N2             1
2014    36           A1         N3             1
2014    36           A2        NULL            2
2014    36           A3         N1            1.5
2014    36           A3         N2            1.5
2014    37           A4         N1             1
2014    37           A5         N1             1
```

I have to Aggregate No of Activities,No of Nodes, and Time Spent for all activities by Week Number. My problem is I cant get correct Time spent on Activities for a week, as you can see ACTIVITYID is repeated in the Table, and if I use sum(ACTIVITY_HOURS_SPENT) I would get 8 for week 36, instead of (1+2+1.5=4.5). Are there any Aggregate functions to solve this kind of problem. I can solve this by Aggregating by Week in ACTIVITY table and joining again with the above table aggregating everything except Hours, but this is taking more time and a costly operation for me. I am looking for an alternate approach.

EDIT: I am doing by this way. The actual tables are very big, The ACTIVITYNODE(this would be a sub query in actual implementation) is the Table I have shown above and it is obtained by doing a LEFT JOIN with ACTIVITY and NODE Tables. ACTIVITYID is Primary KEY in ACTIVITY Table and in NODE table, Nodes related to each ACTIVITYID are stored (so one to many relation).

```
    SELECT t1.YEAR,t1.WeekNUM,t1.[ACTIVITY COUNT],t1.[NODE COUNT],t2.[HOURS]
    (SELECT YEAR,WeekNUM, count( distinct (ACTIVITYID) ) as [ACTIVITY COUNT],
count ( distinct ( NODEID) ) as [NODE COUNT] from ACTIVITYANDNODE group by YEAR,WeekNUM) as t1

    JOIN

    ( SELECT YEAR,WeekNUM,SUM(ACTIVITY_HOURS_SPENT) as [HOURS] from ACTIVITY group by YEAR,WeekNUM ) as t2 
    ON t1.YEAR=t2.YEAR and t1.WeekNUM=t2.WeekNUM
```

Comment: Show us the query you've tried

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. Can you add the result you're trying to get for this data?

Comment: I'm not sure how you get (1+2+1.5=4.5). Those individual values don't align with activities or nodes within week 36.